# What is a Racist Word™?

Tags: word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Racist Word™. (**Disclaimer:** In case anyone feels nervous about this puzzle, Racist Words™ are not actual racist words.)

In addition, the Not Racist Words™ are Not Racist in a related way. Can you also determine what that is?

Use the following examples below to find the rule:

| Racist Words™ | Not Racist Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| BLACK | ALBUM |
| BROAD | CHANT |
| GREAT | CRYPT |
| LARGE | EARTH |
| LIGHT | FIELD |
| NOBLE | GLAND |
| QUICK | HEATH |
| SWEET | OUNCE |
| THICK | TRIES |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Racist Words™,Not Racist Words™  
BLACK,ALBUM  
BROAD,CHANT  
GREAT,CRYPT  
LARGE,EARTH  
LIGHT,FIELD  
NOBLE,GLAND  
QUICK,HEATH  
SWEET,OUNCE  
THICK,TRIES
```

Comment: Random trivia: 'album' is Latin for 'white'. Of course that's not racist ...

Comment: so the White Album is ... like ... *really* white?

Comment: @Rubio Fair Gwen tried to play the White Album for the candidate but found that it was blank.

Comment: Did anyone try comparative frequency analysis in certain politicians' speeches?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I think the answer is

> All words in the list, both Racist™ and Not Racist™, can be appended or prepended with the letters **EN**. For the Racist Words™, the result is just an extension of the root word, while for the Non-Racist Words™, the meaning changes completely.

Racist Words™

> BLACK**EN** 
>  BROAD**EN** 
>  GREAT**EN** 
>  **EN**LARGE 
>  LIGHT**EN** 
>  **EN**NOBLE 
>  QUICK**EN** 
>  SWEET**EN** 
>  THICK**EN**

Non-Racist Words™

> ALBUM**EN** 
>  **EN**CHANT 
>  **EN**CRYPT 
>  EARTH**EN** 
>  **EN**FIELD 
>  **EN**GLAND 
>  HEATH**EN** 
>  **EN**OUNCE 
>  **EN**TRIES

They are called Racist™ because

> I think this is a reference to the "N-word", adding **EN** to the Racist Words™ does not fundamentally change them while adding **EN** to the Non-Racist Words™ completely changes the meaning.

Comment: If this is not the answer, it should be.

Comment: @hexomino: That's correct - well done. What I had in mind is that modifying the words on the left in the way you have stated gives words that mean "to make ___", while doing the same to the words on the right does not.

Comment: Awesome.  Clever question, clever answer.

Comment: By this explanation, I find it strange to consider "earth" a non-racist word.

Comment: @Daniel Wagner I see where you're coming from: earthenware is made of earth. However, the words on the left are all adjectives that are turned into verbs with the sense "to make <adjective>", and that isn't true for EARTH.

Answer (score 8):

Here's my answer:

> Each of the words on the left can be made into a new word by adding the >! letters 'E', 'E', 'N', 'D'
>
>  BLACK**ENED**
>  BROAD**ENED**
>  GREAT**ENED**
>  **EN**LARG**ED**
>  LIGHT**ENED**
>  **EN**NOBL**ED**
>  QUICK**ENED**
>  SWEET**ENED**
>  THICK**ENED**

Comment: I think this doesn't work with **EN**CRYPT**ED** or **EN**CHANT**ED**, which are not supposed to fit the pattern.

Comment: @quarkle: Very close. If you look at the title, you might see how to modify your answer to get the correct one.

Comment: @tmpearce: You are right to notice this. In this particular puzzle, the Not Racist Words™ are Not Racist in a related way.

Comment: Oohh, close. well done! Deserves more votes I think.

Comment: @tmpearce You've never chantened some weapons in your Minecraft world stored on your cryptened hard drive?

Answer (score 8):

Racist words are words that

> can end with "EST"

So:

> BLACKEST, BROADEST, GREATEST, LARGEST, LIGHTEST, NOBLEST, QUICKEST, SWEETEST, THICKEST

are racist words.

Comment: this doesn't work for NOBLE or LARGE.

Comment: [Noblest](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/noblest?s=t) and [Largest](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/largest?s=t) - Both words can end with "EST".  The fact that the base words already end with 'e' is irrelevant.

Comment: ah. i guess that makes sense. gotcha.

Comment: Ermmm... Am I wrong or is it simpler to say they are adjectives in this case?

Comment: @geisterfurz007 - Could be.  I'm stuck on how the "est" relates to "racist" and how to define the "non racist" words.  I'm hoping that someone who's had more coffee than me can supply a fuller answer.

Comment: @Pete: clearly they are, in fact, "racest" and "non-racest" words.

Comment: I dunno... the planet we live on is the Earthest of all the planets in our Solar system.

Answer (score 5):

<s>Racist words are words that</s>

> <s>can be postfixed with NESS to make another word.</s>

There is a simpler explanation:

> all adjectives

are racist words.

Comment: They are, but that isn't the link.

Comment: Naq aba-enpvfg jbeqf ner abhaf. (Forgive my old-fashioned ROT13ing. I don't know how else to hide a spoiler in a comment.)

Answer (score 4):

The words which have superlatives  or in racist terms superior-

> BLACKEST
>  BROADEST
>  GREATEST
>  LARGEST
>  LIGHTEST
>  NOBLEST
>  QUICKEST
>  SWEETEST
>  THICKEST
>
>  Means the one which can end with ST as the title says "Raci**st**"

Comment: This isn't it. The Not Racist Words have been carefully chosen, and part of the puzzle is working out how they fit.